# How to check if polygon or point are below Y value?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

- I have a pandas dataframe which contains column of WKT values.
- The values can be points or polygons
- I want to filter all the points and polygons which are below y=32.

for example:

```
print (df['WKT'].head(3))
```

mistac
gives:

```
    POINT (-3.8891602, 51.1724553)
    POINT (-1.5820313, 53.7162156)
    POLYGON ((-2.2521973 53.1533591, -2.3181152 52.8492299, -1.5490723 52.7695392 -2.2521973 53.1533591
    ))
```

I want to filter all values below `y=52`.
In my example we will filter the second row: `POINT (-3.8891602, 51.1724553)`

How can I do it ?

Comment: Why `head(3)` give 4 rows? Also, is `POINT (-3.8891602, 51.1724553)` string or class object? What's your expected result for `POLYGON ((-2.2521973 53.1533591, -2.3181152, 52.8492299 -1.5490723, 52.7695392 -2.2521973, 53.1533591
    ))`?

Comment: fix it (mistake of copy-paste)

Comment: Also, are you missing some commas in `POLYGON ((-2.2521973 53.1533591, -2.3181152, 52.8492299 -1.5490723, 52.7695392 -2.2521973, 53.1533591
    ))` ??? It's unreadable.

Comment: I update the results

Comment: You cannot just filter a polygon by single y value. Since a polygon formed by multiple x, y values, you have to define your filter accordingly. If you want to filter out polygons with all  y coordinates are below specific value, you have to write a function finding extent or max y , then decide to filter or not.

Answer (score 0):

Since your question is full of typo and I don't really know your expected result, I can't give you a decent answer. But you may try this:

```py
def POINT(a, b):
    return b > 52

def POLYGON(a):
    return 0

s = pd.Series([
    'POINT(-3.8891602, 51.1724553)',
    'POINT(-1.5820313, 53.7162156)'])
```

```
>>> s.apply(lambda x: eval(x))
0    False
1     True
dtype: bool
```